# reboot ubuntu 14 server via cron

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

For whatever my reasons, I want to restart my Ubuntu server every 6 hours via cronjob. I added a cronjob  in crontab -e being the following:

```
* */6 * * * root /sbin/shutdown -r now
```

however I just checked my uptime and it's 10+ hours.

Any ideas?

Comment: what user were you using when you ran `crontab -e`?

Comment: Try to remove the ``root``. If you are editing cronjob with crontab -e as root , you don't have to specify it

Comment: @Dan For whatever your reasons are, restarting separate services is much better approach

Answer (score 3):

Full reboots are not recommended like this.  I think you are already aware of this so here's an answer to your question.

I suspect that your problem is that the `contrab -e` command is designed for a user to add their own cron scripts.  It's not generally used for adding system (root) cron entries.

I believe you would be better to manually add a file in `/etc/crontab.d/` or even add an entry in `/etc/crontab`.

Comment: `/etc/crontab` might get overwritten on system upgrades, so a files in `/etc/crontab.d` is a better choice.